# How to get the proper actions from intent on android

Tags: android, android-intent, action

There are two applications : Caller, Callee

Case 1 >

When I launch Callee application from home screen, I can get an action("android.intent.action.MAIN") from INTENT.

While Callee is running, I launch Callee application with an action("andoird.intent.action.test") again from Caller application. Then I get the action("android.intent.action.MAIN"). not action("andoird.intent.action.test").

How can I get the action("andoird.intent.action.test")?

Case 2 >

When I launch Callee application with an action("andoird.intent.action.test"), I get the action("andoird.intent.action.test").

While Callee is running, I launch Callee application from the home screen. Then I get the action("andoird.intent.action.test"). not action("android.intent.action.Main").

How can I get the action("android.intent.action.Main")?

What am I missing to get the proper action?

Here is Caller code below.

```
public class CallerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String ACTION_TEST = "android.intent.action.test";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotoSetting);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(PACKAGE);
            intent.setAction(ACTION_TEST);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is Callee code below.

```
public class CalleeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.e("test", "onCreate()");
    Log.e("test", getIntent().getAction());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.e("test", "onNewIntent()");
    Log.e("test", getIntent().getAction());
}
```

}

Here is Callee's AndroidManifest.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".CalleeActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.test"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.e("test", "onNewIntent()");
    Log.e("test", getIntent().getAction());// getIntent() will return old intent
}
```

with

```
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.e("test", "onNewIntent()");
    Log.e("test", intent.getAction()); //use new intent
}
```

Comment: OMG!! That is my big mistake!! Thank you!